# onTouchEvent Override in Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to capture onTouchEvent in a completely basic Android Wear app that uses watch view stub.  The onTouchEvent doesn't seem to get called by the MainActivity.

If I put a break in the function onTouchEvent below, it never hits the break point.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {

        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {

            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

}

Comment: try dispatchTouchEvent

Comment: dispatchTouchEvent does get called, but it creates a problem of deactivating all touch events.   So for example: 
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return  super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
Disables all touch events like button clicks, swipe to close, etc.

Comment: Thats why you shouldn't  use Activity's methods,  but rather View's methotds like onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent

Comment: I just add ontouchlistener to the stub and it works.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a wearable app the `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` will be triggered. try overriding `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` as following:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.d("debug", "dispatchTouchEvent");
    return  super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

I hope this help.